# How to get satellite-street map in tileset in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to use satellite-street map using tileset, but it is not available here. It is visible in style and dataset but not in tileset. I want to use mapID, not styleID.

How to get satellite-street map in tileset in Mapbox. It is available in styles and dataset but not in tileset. Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

The raster tileset with the map ID `satellite-streets` would've been a composite of the satellite source (`mapbox.satellite`) and Mapbox Streets source (`mapbox.streets`). These tilesets were created as raster tiles using Mapbox Studio Classic and are no longer supported. Instead, it's recommended to create your own [style](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/create-a-custom-style/) with Mapbox Satellite and Streets sources and use the [Static Tiles endpoint](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-tiles) to generate raster tiles.